# Ransack y multiples modelos en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Necesito tener un formulario que se autocomplete, y estoy usando `Ransack` con `jQuery`, el asunto está con `Ransack`.

EL problema: Necesito tener un formulario que en un único campo busque por dos modelos distintos ó quizas hasta 3.

Tengo los modelos:

```
class Proyecto <ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actividades
end

class Actividad <ActiveRecord::base
 belongs_to :proyecto
def self.search2(dato)
where('LOWER(numero) LIKE :dato', dato: "%#{dato.downcase}%")
end  
end
```

En el controlador:

```
def search
@buscar = Proyecto.ransack(params[:q])
@actividades = @buscar.result.joins(:actividades).select('actividades.numero as actividades_numero, proyectos.nombre as proyecto_nombre')

respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @buscar }
    format.json { @actividades =  Actividad.search2(params[:term])}
  end
end
```

En la vista:

```
<%=search_form_for(@buscar, url: "/administrador/atividades/search", class: "form-inline", role: "form") do |f| %>               
                  <%=f.search_field :actividades_nombre_cont,  class: "form-control", id: "items-search-txt", placeholder: "Coloque el número de la cohorte", style:"width:330px" %>
```

El tema es que no funciona, coloque lo que coloque en `f.search_field`, necesito buscar por nombre de proyecto ó por número de actividad.

Entiendo que debo colocar todos los campos por los cuales buscar de la manera `campo1 or campo2 or campo3 cont` en `f.search_field`, pero ¿Cómo llamo a los campos?

Comment: Solo por adivinar, pero quizás deberías borrar `id: "items-search-txt"`. No recuerdo si cambiar el `id` eventualmente te cambia el `name` del parámetro al momento de hacer el request, pero quizás eso sea lo que te está causando problemas. Para confirmarlo, revisa (o mejor agrega a tu pregunta) lo que te está saliendo en el log del server cuando realizas la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que entiendo que estás intentando: Buscar proyectos, tanto por campos relativos a proyectos como por campos de tablas relacionadas. Ransack te da esa opción:

```
# Controlador
def search
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      @buscar = Proyecto.includes(:actividades).ransack(params[:q])
      @proyectos = @buscar.result
    end
    format.json { @actividades =  Actividad.search2(params[:term])}
  end
end


# Vista.
<%=search_form_for(@buscar, url: "/administrador/atividades/search", class: "form-inline", role: "form") do |f| %>               
  <%=f.search_field :nombre_or_actividades_numero_cont, placeholder: "Busque por número de proyecto o número de actividad", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<% @proyectos.each do |proyecto| %>
...
```

Notas:

- Podría haber agregado el *includes* después e result pero así también debería funcionar.
- Ransack viene con helpers para los formularios y nos permite hacer una búsqueda en múltiples columnas uniéndolas con *_or_*. Ejemplo si tenemos los campos *nombre* y *apellido* y queremos que busque en cualquiera de los dos indistintamente usaríamos: *nombre_or_apellido_cont*. (*_cont* es por *contiene*)
- También nos permite buscar en asociaciones. En ese caso nos pide que incluyamos el nombre de la asociación en la formación del símbolo. En el ejemplo de arriba es *_actividades_numero_cont* asumiendo que la tabla de actividades tiene una columna número por la que quieres buscar. Si en cambio quieres buscar por la ID sería *actividades_id_cont*.
- Como en el ejemplo estoy usando *contains* (*_cont*) y no *equal* (*_eq*) si hago una búsqueda de la actividad 1, me traerá todas las que contengan el número 1: 1, 10, 11, 12, etc. En ese caso mejor usar *_eq*